# run javascript function by url hash

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website which has all pages contents in one page called "pagecontents". When a menu in navbar is clicked the jQuery load function is triggered and the relevant content is loaded into the main page.

It's working fine, however I added an hash to the URL for whenever a particular content is loaded , so that users can go directly into viewing relevant content when they type or paste the  url with the hash. This works fine in my local host but not on remote host I wonder What's the problem.

```
 if(location.hash == '#web') {

              $('#contentFetch').load('pagecontents.php #webC');

            }if(location.hash == '#graphic') {

              $('#contentFetch').load('pagecontents.php #graphicC');

            }if(location.hash == '#mobile') {

              //$('#testLocation').text("mobile Works");
              $('#contentFetch').load('pagecontents.php #mobileC');

            }if(location.hash == '#contact') {

              $('#contentFetch').load('pagecontents.php #contactC');

            }else{ 
                 $('#contentFetch').load('pagecontents.php #indexC');
              }
```

Edit: About the hash in query string:
 the website url ex: 'www.mywebsite.com/'. when i add the '#graphic' at the end: 'www.mywebsite.com/#graphic' it's not loading the content. I noticed that if keep on pressing enter even though is not loading, it then loads!!!?  it seems very incosistent as it loads 1 time out of 5. I wonder if using this is reliable in real world, or is there another way of doing it? Thanks, Mike

Comment: We don't have enough information to know what's not working. Is the PHP file not running? Is the AJAX command unable to find the file? Is the page fragment not in the external file? There could be a number of causes. Does `pagecontents.php` load correctly when you access it directly in the browser?

Comment: 1) URI specs does not allow spaces; 2) the rest of string after hash will not send to server. Use char which designed for uri params - ? `load("pagecontent.php?section=contactC")`

Comment: as Blazemonger taught me, it's an URI that may be followed by a space and a jQuery selector: http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments

Comment: Oh. I thought you want to load different html from the same pagecontent.php. Then you should check if element with needed ID was in response indeed, as @Blazemonger already said.

Comment: When is this snippet executed? OnDOMready, onload, onhashchange?

Comment: @Blazemonger php script works fine, and the 'pageContents.php' does load directly in the browser. and the hashes tag as well. All divs id's are fine.

Comment: @Bergi it's executed onload, i.e. as soon as page loads.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check the runtime versions that your host is using and that they comply with the ones you have locally.

Usually, a host will run a version of a software that is often outdated in order to accommodate older websites. (ex. running PHP 4 instead of PHP 5).

Comment: It's JavaScript, which is executed in the client, not a server-side language like PHP.

Comment: @David But the external file is PHP, and it's possible that file isn't being executed as expected.

Comment: Well if its not running then of course somewhere theres an error. Have you checked with Chrome Dev Tools?

Comment: I really don't think it's a php issue. As I use the same method and pages to load the content when the user goes through the menus. even the jquery function is the same, the only difference being that I copied it and put it on a ini function that runs everything that needs to start as soon as page loads page load, and added a condition that checks for the hashes in URL.

Comment: The remote host is running PHP version 5.3. It's compatible with my server side code.